# Add Printer via C# on Server

Tags: c#, printing, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I want to add a printer to windows via c#.

I programmed the following method:

```
public void AddPrinter(Model.Printer printer)
{
    var printerName = printer.Path;
    var managementScope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
    managementScope.Connect();

   var printerClass = new ManagementClass(new ManagementPath("Win32_Printer"), null);
   var inputParameters = printerClass.GetMethodParameters("AddPrinterConnection");

   inputParameters.SetPropertyValue("Name", printerName);
   printerClass.InvokeMethod("AddPrinterConnection", inputParameters, null);
}
```

This works on a Windows 7/8 Client but does not work on the Server (Windows 2008/2012).

Does somebody know why?
The program seems to run, but no printers are added.
I do not get an exception.

Comment: Use the WMI Code Creator utility to write WMI queries.  It will help you to not ignore the method return value.

Answer (score 1):

When I install a printer from my program, I use a code like this

```
string printerIP = "10.200.49.230";
string portName = "IP_"+printerIP;
string serverName "printServer01";

PrintServer ps = new PrintServer(@"\\" + serverName);

ManagementClass printerPortClass = new ManagementClass("\\\\" + serverName + "\\root\\cimv2", "Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort", new ObjectGetOptions());
printerPortClass.Get();
var newPrinterPort = printerPortClass.CreateInstance();
newPrinterPort.SetPropertyValue("Name", portName);
newPrinterPort.SetPropertyValue("Protocol", 1);
newPrinterPort.SetPropertyValue("HostAddress", PrinterIP);
newPrinterPort.SetPropertyValue("PortNumber", 9100);
newPrinterPort.SetPropertyValue("SNMPEnabled", false);
newPrinterPort.Put();
//install printer
try
{
    ps.InstallPrintQueue(
        "PrinterName",
        "DriverName",
        new String[] { portName },    //port_name
        "WinPrint",
        PrintQueueAttributes.Shared,//set it to shared
        "Sharename",
        "This is a comment for the printer",
        "This is the printers location",
        "", 1, 1        //priorities
        );
}
catch (Exception printerException)
{
    //couldn't install printer
}
```

In essense, I use the PrintServer in C# to connect to the Print Server. I also use WMI to make a port to set the printer on. In my company we use "IP_"+[ip of printer] but you can make it pretty much whatever you want.

After I've created the port I "install" the printer. It's not really an installation as the driver needs to already be installed on the server, but this works for me.

Comment: You made this by yourself? Do i need to add a reference?

Comment: the PrintServer class is located in System.Printing and the ManagementClass is located in System.Management, yes you need to add them as references.